# How are you supposed to handle a spurious wakeup of a Parker?

Tags: rust, synchronization

According to the `crossbeam::Parker` [documentation](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.7.3/crossbeam/sync/struct.Parker.html#method.park):

> The park method blocks the current thread unless or until the token is available, at which point it automatically consumes the token. It may also return spuriously, without consuming the token.

How are you supposed to detect that a spurious wakeup occurred? Internally, it appears that the parker uses an atomic to track if the token has been consumed or not, but aside from the `park` and `park_timeout` methods, there doesn't seem to be a way to query its status.

Comment: The documentation seems inconsistent. The source code shows a loop that goes back to sleep when a spurious wakeup is detected, but only when there is no timeout, so in this case there can be no spurious wakeups. Since there is no indication of completion, the interface with a timeout doesn't seem usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been [acknowledged](https://github.com/crossbeam-rs/crossbeam/issues/482#issuecomment-688498188) as an issue on the relevant GitHub, and a [pull request](https://github.com/crossbeam-rs/crossbeam/pull/563) has been filed to fix it. Once that pull request is merged and released, I'll update this answer with the version that fixes the issue and mark this question as resolved.

UPDATE: This has been resolved since at least crossbeam 0.8.2

Answer (score -1):

You are supposed to handle it in some other manner. For example, if you are implementing an mpsc channel manually, your `recv` function might look something like this:

```
loop {
    if let Some(message) = self.try_recv() {
        return message;
    }
    park();
}
```

In this case, if a spurious wake-up happen, the loop will try to obtain the thing it is waiting for again, but since it was a spurious wake-up, the thing is not available, and the loop just goes to sleep again. Once a `send` actually happens, the sender will unpark the receiver, at which point the `try_recv` will succeed.

An example of such a channel implementation is available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4mS5UPHh20) ([source](https://gist.github.com/jonhoo/935060885d0d832d463fda3c89e8259d)), although it uses a `CondVar` instead of parking the thread, but it is the same idea.

Comment: This makes no sense. The parker wraps a condition variable, a mutex, and a flag. In the normal comfortable POSIX world, when you wake up, *the mutex is locked* so you can check the condition without other threads interfering. You cannot do the same here because the mutex is hidden, so you need a different mutex. Fail!

Comment: Are you referring to the linked channel implementation? The `wait` function consumes the mutex guard, and unlocks it until `wait` returns, at which point the mutex is locked again, and the new mutex guard is returned.

Comment: Condvar+mutex is a pretty standard thing for producer/consumer scenarios. I don't know exactly how channels work but they seem to be very similar to producer/consumer queues, so they are implemented in the same way with condvar+mutex. And this is exactly the problem with parking, you don't get to see the mutex. There is an internal flag that is set before the wake up call, which would be plenty enough, but you don't get to see it either!

Comment: Well, I suppose that is the reason that the example I found uses a `CondVar` instead of parking. However, the pattern for how you handle spurious wake-ups is the same for each type of synchronization primitive, so I do still think it answers the question.  An example where parking is more suitable than `CondVar` would be building an executor for async code. In this case, the futures need to wake you up somehow, but there's no associated mutex. Parking is the perfect solution there, and the same loop applies, as you just check if there are futures ready to poll when woken up.

Comment: Frankly I don't quite understand this. There is that atomic boolean flag inside the parker implementation. Instead of checking a potentially expensive external condition, like the future in your example, you could just check the flag, which is set precisely when the wake up is not spurious. But no, it is not exposed.